# Download arquivo excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Criei um arquivo em excel, mas agora o usuário precisa fazer o download, como posso fazer ?  segue meu método :

```cs
    public PartialViewResult ExportarParticipantes(int idPeriodo)
    {

        Regex reg = new Regex("[/ :]");

        // Monta arquivo para análise
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", reg.Replace(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "_").Replace("&", ""), Path.GetFileName("passagens.xls"));

        string caminhoArquivo = Path.Combine(Caminho, fileName);

        ExcelHelper excelHelper = new ExcelHelper(caminhoArquivo);

        // Obtém dados
        Dictionary<string, int> colunas = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        UploadPassagem lstParticipantePassagem = null;
        List<UploadPassagem> lista = new List<UploadPassagem>();

        GerenciaPassagemModel model = new GerenciaPassagemModel();

        Periodo periodo = new PeriodoService().ListarPorId(idPeriodo);

        model.Mensagem = ValidarPeriodo(periodo);
        model.ListaPassagens = new PassagemService().ListarPassagensPorPeriodo(idPeriodo, true);


        foreach (var item in model.ListaPassagens)
        {
            lstParticipantePassagem = new UploadPassagem(); 
            lstParticipantePassagem.PARTICIPANTE = item.Participante.NomeCompleto;
            lstParticipantePassagem.CPF = item.Participante.CPF;
            lstParticipantePassagem.PASSAGEM = item.Passagens.ToString();
            lstParticipantePassagem.CONCESSIONÁRIA = item.Participante.EstruturaAtual.EstruturaNome;
            lstParticipantePassagem.STATUS = item.Acao == true ? "Aprovado" : item.Acao == false ? "Recusado" : "Pendente";

            lista.Add(lstParticipantePassagem);

        }


        excelHelper.Export<UploadPassagem>(lista);

        return PartialView("_ListaParticipante", model);
    }
```

Comment: Acho que nesse caso podemos abstrair a geração do arquivo. Você poderia deixar um pseudo-código menor, onde assume que o arquivo será criado corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando o EPPlus, eis como estou a fazer:

```
var memoryStream = package.GetAsByteArray();

return base.File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName); //fileName é o nome do teu ficheiro
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos dizer que você criou em uma pasta dentro do seu projeto `Arquivo`. Dentro dela possui um arquivo `EXCEL`(`xls`) com o nome de ***Pasta1.xls*** ao qual deseja fazer um download. Utilize no método do tipo de retorno [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

***Código***

```
public FileContentResult Excel()
{
      byte[] Excel = null;

      Excel = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Arquivo/Pasta1.xls"));

      return new FileContentResult(Excel, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

***No seu Código***

```
public FileContentResult ExportarParticipantes(int idPeriodo)
{

    Regex reg = new Regex("[/ :]");

    // Monta arquivo para análise
    string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", reg.Replace(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "_").Replace("&", ""), Path.GetFileName("passagens.xls"));

    string caminhoArquivo = Path.Combine(Caminho, fileName);

    ExcelHelper excelHelper = new ExcelHelper(caminhoArquivo);

    // Obtém dados
    Dictionary<string, int> colunas = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    UploadPassagem lstParticipantePassagem = null;
    List<UploadPassagem> lista = new List<UploadPassagem>();

    GerenciaPassagemModel model = new GerenciaPassagemModel();

    Periodo periodo = new PeriodoService().ListarPorId(idPeriodo);

    model.Mensagem = ValidarPeriodo(periodo);
    model.ListaPassagens = new PassagemService().ListarPassagensPorPeriodo(idPeriodo, true);


    foreach (var item in model.ListaPassagens)
    {
        lstParticipantePassagem = new UploadPassagem();
        lstParticipantePassagem.PARTICIPANTE = item.Participante.NomeCompleto;
        lstParticipantePassagem.CPF = item.Participante.CPF;
        lstParticipantePassagem.PASSAGEM = item.Passagens.ToString();
        lstParticipantePassagem.CONCESSIONÁRIA = item.Participante.EstruturaAtual.EstruturaNome;
        lstParticipantePassagem.STATUS = item.Acao == true ? "Aprovado" : item.Acao == false ? "Recusado" : "Pendente";

        lista.Add(lstParticipantePassagem);

    }


    excelHelper.Export<UploadPassagem>(lista);

    byte[] Excel = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoArquivo);            

    return new FileContentResult(Excel, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O mais correto é especificar uma `Action` no `Controller` que devolva um `FileResult`. Por exemplo:

```
public FileResult ExportarExcel()
{
    // Monte aqui o arquivo Excel.
    // conteudoDoArquivo deve ser um byte[]

    return new File(conteudoDoArquivo, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "nomeDoArquivo.xls");
}
```

Comment: Cara meu conteudo do arquivo é uma List, como transforma-lo em byte[] ??

Comment: @SirSmart Qual o retorno desta linha? `excelHelper.Export<UploadPassagem>(lista);`

Comment: Não tenho retorno dessa linha... Desculpa mas ainda não entendi aonde vc quer chegar...

Comment: Não sei como funciona seu `ExcelHelper`, mas suponho que ele devolva um objeto que represente o arquivo Excel construído de alguma forma. É preciso representar ele como um array de bytes para que ele possa ser retornado. Feito esse array de bytes, coloque ele no lugar de `conteudoDoArquivo` que ao chamar a Action `ExportarExcel do seu `Controller`, o resultado será um download.

Answer (score 1):

Usa assim!

```
 private void ExportarParaExcel(){

    DataTable odt = RetornaBuscaDoBanco();

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(odt, "nomeaquivo");

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=nomeaquivo" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ".xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
        }
    }
}
```